# How do I track 400 keywords with Twitter using the Streaming API?

Tags: python, twitter, streaming

I have 400 urls that I want to track in the Streaming API, and I'm allowed to have 400 keywords (the urls) to track as per the streaming api.

However, the url I end up querying with is too large for a standared post request and doesn't work. In the Twitter Docs, it says `increaded access levels allow up to 10000 keywords`, how does that work with so many keywords in a url?

I'm using Python btw, 
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a little confusing -- I assume you must be doing GET rather than POST, as there's no real limit on POSTs.  From the [API docs](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#statuses-filter):

> Placing long parameters in the URL may
>   cause the request to be rejected for
>   excessive URL length. Use a POST
>   request header parameter to avoid long
>   URLs.

So the first thing I would do is make sure you're using POST and not GET. If that doesn't do the trick, it would be helpful if you provided some more details about what sort of errors you are getting back, and perhaps exactly how you are trying to consume the API.